# BPMN to BPEL tool

Tags: bpel, bpmn

Do you know any open source tool that helps to transform BPMN models to BPEL definitions and then executes them in a BPEL process engine?

In my research so far, I extend the BPMN 2.0 metamodel and want to develop a prototype tool that has full support from modeling to executing a business process. Currently my prototype tool allows the modeling of extended BPMN models. But I want to generate BPEL executables and I don't want to implement everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

A transformer of BPMN 1.2 to executable BPEL is available as part of the oryx project here:
http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/source/browse/trunk/editor/server/src/de/hpi/bpmn2bpel/

Input: eRDF description of a BPMN 1.2 process.
Output: BPEL process, deployment descriptor for Apache ODE, and WSDL file

The transformer is based on a BPMN 1.0 to BPEL4Chor transformer, which used the idea of the following research paper:
Ouyang, C.; Dumas, M.; ter Hofstede, A. & van der Aalst, W. Pattern-based Translation of BPMN Process Models to BPEL Services International Journal of Web Services Research, 2008, 5, 42-61

We internally developed a transformer based on the [Refined Process Structure Tree](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-85758-7_10), but did not manage to make a release. If anyone wants to help getting the thing ready, please get in touch with me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Intalio|BPMS. The Designer lets you design the process using BPMN, and transforms it to BPEL.

Comment: Where does one find the source code of the designer with the transformation code? At http://bpms.intalio.com/download/, there is only the binary available for downloading. Or did I see something wrong?